# Nib loaded, outlets missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

In my project some `UITableViewCell` have some complex subview structure and gesture action, so I decided to use a layer of "cell controller" objects (subclasses of `NSObject`) to manage the cells and cell-layer gestures, as well as drawing the cell in a xib file.

Now when I load the cell from the nib with cell controller as its owner (the xib is properly set up) I found the outlets not connected. Why?

Or, is there any method that is called on the owner object when a nib is loaded and outlets is set up?

Nib is loaded like this:

```
cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HistoryCellActive"
                                     owner:self
                                   options:nil][0];
```

Comment: Can you show us how you loaded the nib file?

Comment: @ozgur `-[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]` as the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The nib-loading infrastructure sends an [awakeFromNib](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib) message to each object recreated from a nib archive. When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.

You may try to override awakeFromNib method in the HistoryCellActive implementation file and put a breakpoint here. If cell xib file is correct the debugger stops in this breakpoint and you can check all cell's outlets. If no then you have to check xib for mistakes.

Don't forget to call [super awakeFromNib]; at the beginning of awakeFromNib implemetation.

Comment: Not of much help: HistoryCellActive is just a UITableViewCell so there is nowhere I can breakpoint on.

Comment: If its just a UITableViewCell what outlets you are talking about?

Comment: If you want to attach custom outlets to UITableViewCell you should make a subclass of UITableViewCell and define outlets here.

Comment: I have a cell controller object that owns the xib and the missing outlets points to that.

Comment: If you have a class implementation of your "cell controller object" you may override awakeFromNib here.

Comment: Tried, not get called.